# Canvas.toDataURL() Workaround?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Okay, so a friend of mine asked me to help him out with creating a canvas painting application for a mobile site he's working on. However, he was unable to get the "paintings" to save to the server. I did a little checking and it appears that in the current iteration of the browser (based on WebKIt IIRC), .toDataURL support was randomly thrown out. Is there any workaround  for this that'll allow the canvas data to be sent via a POST request?

**Edit:**

> Browser- Netfront(R) Browser, NX v.1.0

It simply appears that the browser doesn't support it

```
canvas = document.getElementById('paint');
var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL();
var datafield = document.getElementById('dataurl');
datafield.value = imagedata;
document.forms["imagedatahold"].submit();
```

On the file that is to receive the data, the querystring is empty. This is not the case in any other browser as far as I can tell.

The value of "imagedata" is returning as:

> data:,

Comment: toDataURL has not been 'thrown out'. It is still very present. What is the context of the usage, and what is the error message seen?

Comment: Ah, I thought I covered that in my question. However, the browser for the device definitely doesn't support it. In essentially every other browser I've tested it in, it works fine, so I don't think it's an issue with the code. I used some code I found to detect support for it and it confirmed that the browser indeed lacks support for it.

Comment: What OS? What browser? What version? What is the code? What is the exact error message?

Comment: I've moved your comment as an edit to your question (that's where is should go). If the querystring is empty, that means the form is being submit. If the form is being submit, you're not getting an error when `toDataURL()` runs. So...find a way to log or `alert()` or otherwise confirm what the value of `imagedata` is.

Comment: The value I get has been added to my question by the way.

Comment: Great; I now fully believe you :) Looks like a JS image encoder (using the image data from the canvas) is your only bet…assuming that you can get image data. @gion_13's answer looks reasonable, though there appear to be several other JS-only options.

Comment: Google for "JavaScript PNG encoder" or some such. That's how I found them. I have no experience with any, so I won't post them as an answer. (Just running a Google search for you and linking to libraries is not a reasonable answer.)

Answer (score 6):

I used to have a problem with a web app running on android devices.
The problem was that android didn't have a `toDataURL` method implementation, so I ended up using this implementation : http://code.google.com/p/todataurl-png-js/ .
It may be a bit slower, but it gets the job done.